# Windows Azure Dev Fabric Configuration for SQL Server

Tags: configuration, azure

Where do I go to configure the Windows Azure Dev Fabric to use SQL Server Developer Edition instead of SQL Server Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179457.aspx.